# My object responds to other object's change. How can I change the color of a single button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list view full of buttons, I would like for the button that was pressed to light change color, however I also want to keep a clean non repetitive code, therefore when I click one button all buttons change color. How can I fix that?

Here is the main code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'seasons.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TradingPage());
}

class TradingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffaa249e),
          title: Text('Relatable'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 3,
                blurRadius: 6,
                offset: Offset(0, 1),
              )
            ],
          ),
          height: 30.0,
          child: SeasonListWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Season venus = Season('Venus');
Season helado = Season('Helado');
Season year1800s = Season('1800s');
Season neon = Season('Neon');
Season ritmo = Season('Ritmo');
Season lente = Season('Lente');
Season gemas = Season('Gemas');

var seasonsList = [venus, helado, year1800s, neon, ritmo, lente, gemas];

class SeasonListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SeasonListWidgetState createState() => _SeasonListWidgetState();
}

class _SeasonListWidgetState extends State<SeasonListWidget> {
  var clicked = 0xff808080;
  @override
  Center seasonBarItem({required Season season}) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              clicked = 0xff000000;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            season.name,
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(clicked)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      itemExtent: 75.0,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        seasonBarItem(season: venus),
        seasonBarItem(season: helado),
        seasonBarItem(season: year1800s),
        seasonBarItem(season: neon),
        seasonBarItem(season: ritmo),
        seasonBarItem(season: lente),
        seasonBarItem(season: gemas),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the season object:

```
import 'main.dart';

class Season<Widget> {
  String name;

  Season(this.name);

  void changeNameColor() {}
}
```

Anyone that helps I will love for eternity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a property called color in the Season. I made more some refactoring too. I hope you like.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TradingPage());
}

class TradingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TradingPageState createState() => _TradingPageState();
}

class _TradingPageState extends State<TradingPage> {
  Season venus = Season('Venus');
  Season helado = Season('Helado');
  Season year1800s = Season('1800s');
  Season neon = Season('Neon');
  Season ritmo = Season('Ritmo');
  Season lente = Season('Lente');
  Season gemas = Season('Gemas');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffaa249e),
          title: Text('Relatable'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 3,
                blurRadius: 6,
                offset: Offset(0, 1),
              )
            ],
          ),
          height: 30.0,
          child: ListView(
            itemExtent: 75.0,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              seasonBarItem(season: venus),
              seasonBarItem(season: helado),
              seasonBarItem(season: year1800s),
              seasonBarItem(season: neon),
              seasonBarItem(season: ritmo),
              seasonBarItem(season: lente),
              seasonBarItem(season: gemas),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Center seasonBarItem({required Season season}) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              season.color = 0xff000000;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            season.name,
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(season.color)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Season<Widget> {
  String name;

  int color = 0xff808080;

  Season(this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(I thought that it can be selected one item only)

- Added 'clickedIndex' variable to store selected bar item
- Added parameter index at seasonBarItem to distinguish item
- If 'clickedIndex' and index of seasonBarItem is same, change text color to selected color.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TradingPage());
}

class TradingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffaa249e),
          title: Text('Relatable'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 3,
                blurRadius: 6,
                offset: Offset(0, 1),
              )
            ],
          ),
          height: 30.0,
          child: SeasonListWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Season venus = Season('Venus');
Season helado = Season('Helado');
Season year1800s = Season('1800s');
Season neon = Season('Neon');
Season ritmo = Season('Ritmo');
Season lente = Season('Lente');
Season gemas = Season('Gemas');

var seasonsList = [venus, helado, year1800s, neon, ritmo, lente, gemas];

class SeasonListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SeasonListWidgetState createState() => _SeasonListWidgetState();
}

class _SeasonListWidgetState extends State<SeasonListWidget> {
  int clickedIndex = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Center seasonBarItem({@required Season season, @required index}) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              clickedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            season.name,
            style: TextStyle(
              color:
                  clickedIndex == index ? Color(0xff000000) : Color(0xff808080),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 75.0,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return seasonBarItem(season: seasonsList[index], index: index);
      },
    );
  }
}

class Season<Widget> {
  String name;

  Season(this.name);

  void changeNameColor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your objects are linked to `clicked` var. So calling `setState` is rebuilding the whole widget tree and all widgets are getting this var as color. For your purpose you can create list of colors and change index of chosen element.